# Calculate physical size for a single row in a table with sql server

Tags: sql-server, database

I am creating an application to provide limited space in database as gmail account. I want to charge from customer as per their data storage space. I have googled but not found proper solution.

I want to calculate the physical size (Hard disk space) for a single row of a particular ID from different tables in a database. I am using sql server.

Take an example to understand this:

We all are use gmail and have a limited space 5GB for our mail storage space on server. When we exceed the limit of storage space then we have to remove some data from our account to get free space(as also use in hard disk).

There may some different functionality for gmail as per my thought but I need this.

Note: This post may be repeated/duplicated. You are welcome to ask frankly.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I've encountered this problem before and the best solution I found was finding out the total size of the table (indexes included) and dividing it for the amount of rows it has. This is useful if your table represents an entity that doesn't have a wide data length deviation from the mean (which was my case), and you also have enough rows and data to represent real cases.

The query to see size used by table:

```
SELECT 
    TableName = t.NAME,
    SchemaName = s.Name,
    [RowCount] = p.rows,
    TotalSpaceMB = CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 / 1024.0), 
    UsedSpaceMB = CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 / 1024.0),
    UnusedSpaceMB = CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 / 1024.0)
FROM 
    sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
    INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, 
    s.Name, 
    p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    TotalSpaceMB DESC
```

You would then divide `UsedSpaceMB` by `RowCount` to get average size.

Comment: This worked great for me. I just added "AvgRowSizeKB = ROUND(((CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 )) / NULLIF(p.rows,0)), 3)" right above the from line and I was good to go! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to calculate the exact storage size in the presence of nullable columns, variable length data types, per-page overhead and compression. I'd use one of these pragmatic approaches:

1. Estimate the storage size for each row using a simple formula. Keep it simple. 4 byte per integer. 1 or 2 bytes of storage for all string columns (depending on whether they are varchar or nvarchar). Then, take the total table size (which is easy to find out exactly) and split it up among all customers according to the estimated storage size. That way you can fairly distribute all overhead and compression savings that you get. You can be sure that all bytes of the table are accounted for and payed for.
2. Partition the table by customer and make them pay for the exact storage space they use. Be aware of the limits regarding maximum partition count.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that this isn't a direct answer to the question, but you can use
**sp_spaceused** *table name*  to see how much space a table is taking up (and how much is used).

```
EXEC sp_spaceused N'[dbo].[sysdiagrams]';

name         rows  reserved  data    index_size  unused  
------------ ----- --------- ------- ----------- --------
sysdiagrams  303   264 KB    200 KB  16 KB       48 KB
```

You could then compute various lengths of representative columns and divide the cost up that way to compute the space of a specific row.

Hope that helps someone.